# WatchKit WKInterfaceGroup, one label on top of another?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable, wkinterfacegroup, wkinterfacelabel

Simple question: is it possible to stack one `WKInterfaceLabel` on top of another inside a `WKInterfaceGroup`? I’m dragging like a mad man and I cannot get the blue target line to setting above or below the first label. It’ll sit beside it, to its left or right, but it won’t settle above or below it.

I’m trying to do something inside a table row akin to a master/detail, but I simply can’t figure out if it’s possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the layout of the `WKInterfaceGroup` as `Vertical` and that will make your labels be one on top of the other.

[image]

This happens because `WKInterfaceGroup` doesn't work like a view, it has a layout flow that automatically arranges the inner `WKInterface`'s as specified by the Layout property that can be `horizontal` or `vertical`. You can also tweak the appearance with custom insets.

Comment: Glad i helped ! I also added a pic and a small explanation just in case anyone else bumps into this problem.

Comment: anyone got an idea if you want to float labels next to each other AND on top of each other in the same group?

Comment: @dan I would use horizontal and play with custom insets just below the Layout option, until you get the horizontal elements to break to the next line.